# How to know if a camera lens is for micro 4/3 cameras?

Tags: lens, camera-basics, micro-four-thirds

Hey guys [I'm seeing this LUMIX G 42.5mm F1.7 ASPH lens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VQ2CZV8) but I'm not sure if it's for my micro 4/3 camera:

Comment: The box for the lens has the MF3 logo on. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Panasonic-LUMIX-G-42-5mm-F1-7-ASPH-POWER-H-HS043-S-Silver-Lens-for-MFT/273523463967?hash=item3faf44d71f:g:c90AAOSwja5e4XYD

Answer (score 2):

All Lumix G series lenses are for the Micro Four Thirds system.

From the listing for the [LUMIX G 42.5mm F1.7 ASPH (H-HS043)](https://www.panasonic.com/ca/consumer/cameras-camcorders/interchangeable-lenses/micro-four-thirds/h-hs043.html) at Panasonic's website:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google it, it appears to be for micro 4/3:

https://www.panasonic.com/ca/consumer/cameras-camcorders/interchangeable-lenses/micro-four-thirds/h-hs043.html